# returning value from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, netbeans-7

class1- The dynamic values of the coordinates is saved and want to return the values to the function of the class2.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {    

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }    

    ArrayList<Integer> al= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
      int x= evt.getX();
      int y= evt.getY();          
      al.add(x);
      al.add(y);
       System.out.println("hi1"+al);
    }
     public ArrayList<Integer> cord()
     {
          System.out.println("hi2"+al);
         return al;
     }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }       

    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;       
}
```

class2

```
public class JavaApplication13 {

    public void hello()
    {
        NewJFrame j= new NewJFrame();
        ArrayList<Integer> al=j.cord();
        System.out.println("hi3"+al);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaApplication13 j= new JavaApplication13();
        j.hello();
    }
}
```

I want to return the values of the x and y coordinate from class1 to class2. but it displays null. Help.

Answer (score 0):

In `NewJFrame` class make `ArrayList<Integer> al` public static and in `JavaApplication13` read it `System.out.println("hi3"+NewJFrame.al.get())`. Of course this aproach is just one from quadrillion ways how to do it and your code has some problems: you can't (i supose you are goind to get some value from ArrayList) do `"hi3"+al`.